# OmniAuth / Rails - You have a nil object when you didn't expect it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, omniauth

I'm getting the following error in my Rails application and I have no idea how to go about debugging or fixing it:

> NoMethodError in
>   AuthenticationsController#create
>
> You have a nil object when you didn't
>   expect it! You might have expected an
>   instance of ActiveRecord::Base. The
>   error occurred while evaluating nil.[]
>
> Rails.root:
>   /Users/phil/Sites/travlrapp.com
>   Application Trace | Framework Trace |
>   Full Trace
>
> app/controllers/authentications_controller.rb:15:in
>   `create'

The controller is this:

```
class AuthenticationsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @authentications = current_user.authentications if current_user
  end

    def create

        omniauth = request.env["omniauth.auth"]

        unless omniauth
            redirect_to authentications_url
            flash[:notice] = "Could not authenticate via #{params['provider']}."
        end

        authentication = Authentication.find_by_provider_and_uid(omniauth['provider'], omniauth['uid'])
        if authentication
            flash[:notice] = "Signed in successfully."
            sign_in_and_redirect(:user, authentication.user)
        elsif current_user

            current_user.authentications.create!(:provider => omniauth['provider'], :uid => omniauth['uid'], :token => omniauth['credentials']['token'], :secret => omniauth['credentials']['secret'])
            flash[:notice] = "Authentication successful."
            redirect_to authentications_url
        else
            user = User.new
            user.apply_omniauth(omniauth)
            if user.save
                flash[:notice] = "Signed in successfully."
                sign_in_and_redirect(:user, user)
            else
                session[:omniauth] = omniauth.except('extra')
                redirect_to new_user_registration_url
            end
        end
    end


  def destroy
    @authentication = current_user.authentications.find(params[:id])
    @authentication.destroy
    flash[:notice] = "Successfully destroyed authentication."
    redirect_to authentications_url
  end
end
```

OmniAuth used to work fine, then I mashed it up trying to swap to a fork by pchilton which supported flickr. I did this by setting :git => in the gemfile and trying to reinstall but im not confident I ever did it right.

I have now manually removed all omniauth and oa- foo gem files and installed first the current stable (0.1.6) and the git master copy but all errors are the same.

Really at a loss here, nobody I know has any idea what the problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seemed to randomly fix itself. Go Rails!

Answer (score 2):

It's probable that `omniauth` is `nil`.  While you are checking for nil with `unless onmniauth`, the `redirect_to` doesn't actually stop the controller code below from executing.

You probably want something like this:

```
unless omniauth
  redirect_to authentications_url
  flash[:notice] = "Could not authenticate via #{params['provider']}."
  return
end
```

Now, you still need to figure out why `omniauth` is `nil`.  For that, make sure you are using OmniAuth correctly by looking at the [README](https://github.com/intridea/omniauth/blob/master/README.markdown).  Is `/auth/provider/callback` routed to `AuthenticationsController#create` ?

Answer (score 1):

I apologize in advance if you already know this method (you are a php developer after all).

Does rails support php style debugging similar to `die()` ? I have encountered weird incomprehensible error like this in both yii and kohana php frameworks.

What I do is put a `die('AAAAA')` at the end of the controller acion, and gradually move it up until *IT* gets triggered before the error does, that way I know exactly on what line the error was.

Then i move it into whatever function is called on that line and start again.

I don't know if rails supports this kind of raw debug style. Also it would help if the source code for those gems are in noncompiled code so you can insert `die()` all over the place like that.

You could do something like the equivalent of `echo 'AAA'; exit;` or something similar.

Also there is also the 'check if a function gets called: `die('BBBBB');` :P

If you want to go really advanced there is also

`die("AAAAA ".' '.__FILE__.'::Line:'.__LINE__);`

Comment: Sure that sort of debugging works fine in PHP but its a little different in Rails. You can use puts "foo" to output to the console instead of the browser, which acts like a "breakpoint" showing that rails has read that line. Puts seemed to be ignored for me which was one problem I had with debugging, but seems to be working now. Which is weird.

Comment: If you're using Ruby 1.9 you can also use `Object#tap` to inject debugging code without adding separate `puts` statements. See here: http://blog.moertel.com/articles/2007/02/07/ruby-1-9-gets-handy-new-method-object-tap

Comment: You can also `raise` the object (`raise omniauth`).  It'll cause an error and print out the object nicely.